# How to add a baseclass/Interface to EF6 autogenerated Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have generated EF context from the database. Now i want all entities to inherit from a base entity so that i can refer to all entities by using this base entity.

```
Public Partial Class Lookup : BaseEntity
{
}
```

Whenever I am trying to use, DbSet.Add(entity)

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T:IRepositoryEntity
{
    #region Private member variables...
    internal March2016Entities Context;
    internal DbSet<T> DbSet;
    #endregion

    #region Public Constructor...
    /// <summary>
    /// Public Constructor,initializes privately declared local variables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public GenericRepository(March2016Entities context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// generic Insert method for the entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    public  void Insert(T entity)
    {

        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

It says BaseEntity is not part of EF model. I have tried to modify the Context.TT class but it seems that it will only helf in generating entity classes inheriting from the base class.

How can i add this baseclass to entity model so that operations can work? Please suggest.

Comment: No problem doing what you're trying to do. Probably you are creating/adding a BaseEntity to the DbSet (and you can't). Try to make it abstract and compile the project so you will see where you are doing this.

Comment: I have added the exact code line that is throwing exception. When i do DBSet.Add(Lookup entity), it throws error.

Comment: Can you also show us the DBSet declaration?

Comment: Added DBSet declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to narrow down the problem. DBSet was of type BaseEntity and i was trying to insert a entity using a DBSet of BaseEntity. EF was correct in throwing this exception. This was becuase Repository was being returned as of Type BaseEntry. As soon as I got the repository of Type entity, problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

can you also add the code for IRepositoryEntity, I was thinking that should be the BaseEntity? and also make your baseEntity abstract.